# How to retrieve information about user from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve information of particular user from database using php based on username on my pageview,but it showing error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE,
>   expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\wamp\www\New
>   folder\profileview.php on line 5

Code

```
<?php 
// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error()); 
$SQL="SELECT * FROM members WHERE userName=$_SESSION['userName']"; 
or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query($SQL);
Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
Print "<tr>"; 
Print "<th>First Name:</th> <td>".$info['fname'] . "</td> "; 
Print "<th>Middle Name:</th> <td>".$info['mname'] . "</td> "; 
Print "<th>Last Name:</th> <td>".$info['lname'] . "</td> "; 
Print "<th>UserName:</th> <td>".$info['userName'] . "</td> "; 
Print "<th>Gender:</th> <td>".$info['gender'] . "</td> "; 
Print "<th>Date Of Birth:</th> <td>".$info['dob'] . "</td> "; 
Print "<th>Mobile Number:</th> <td>".$info['mobile'] . "</td> "; 
Print "<th>Pet:</th> <td>".$info['pet'] . " </td></tr>"; 
} 
 Print "</table>"; 
?>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
  $SQL="SELECT * FROM members WHERE `userName`='".$_SESSION['userName']."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little late, but if you still haven't solved your problem, this will do the trick.

```
<?php
// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE userName='" . $_SESSION['userName'] . "'" or die(mysql_error());

$data = mysql_query($SQL);
echo "<table border cellpadding=3>";
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>First Name:</th> <td>".$info['fname'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<th>Middle Name:</th> <td>".$info['mname'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<th>Last Name:</th> <td>".$info['lname'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<th>UserName:</th> <td>".$info['userName'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<th>Gender:</th> <td>".$info['gender'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<th>Date Of Birth:</th> <td>".$info['dob'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<th>Mobile Number:</th> <td>".$info['mobile'] . "</td> ";
    echo "<th>Pet:</th> <td>".$info['pet'] . " </td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM members WHERE userName=$_SESSION['userName']"; 
or die(mysql_error());
```

try this

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM members WHERE userName=$_SESSION['userName']"
or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this statement:

```
    $SQL="SELECT * FROM members WHERE userName=$_SESSION['userName']";
```

With this:

```
    $SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE userName='".$_SESSION['userName']."'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: now it showing Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\New folder\profileview.php on line 5

Comment: You forgot . concatenation

Comment: Thanks @RohitKumarChoudhary
Pls. refer to Janak Prajapati's answer. that's the one!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $SQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE userName='".$_SESSION['userName']."'"); 
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your $SQL call to:

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM members WHERE userName=$_SESSION['userName']" or die(mysql_error());
```

A hint:
You're using the deprecated mysql_* functions. Switch to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

And you should never put variables directly into your query, because this can open a door for sql injections.

Use [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains some issues which I would like to highlight here.

1. Whenever you match a string in SQL, always take care it should be within quotes.
2. Write SQL within single quotes, its a better approach
3. As there are some Sql injections issue so always wrap your parameters in mysql_real_escape sting function.
4. Use trim to avoid any chances of bug.

Now keeping all that in mind your query will be like

```
$SQL='SELECT * FROM members WHERE userName=\''.mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_SESSION['userName'])).'\';
```

**PS: please don't practise to use mysql_ functions as they are deprecated.**

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code comes from an extra " ; " in your 4th line of code.
Replace the line you have with this one. It should work.

`$SQL="SELECT * FROM members WHERE userName='" . $_SESSION['userName'] ."'" or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

$data  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE userName= '".$_SESSION['userName']."' ")or die(mysql_error());